# Using ViewPager and AsyncTask together

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

If I start an `AsyncTask` within the `getItem()` function of a `ViewPager` Adapter, passing the Fragment `getItem()` later returns to the `AsyncTask` as a parameter (see below).

Can I then call a method belonging to the Fragment (`setString()`) in the `AsyncTask`s `onPostExecute` and will this still affect the Fragment shown even though it has most likely already been returned by the `ViewPager`s `getItem()` before the `AsyncTask` completes?

```
private class SlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

                MyListFragment listfrag = new MyListFragment(); //Create the fragment
                new AsyncTaskLoader(listfrag).execute(); //Start the AsyncTask, passing the Fragment
                return listfrag;
        }

}
```

And my AsyncTask in the same Activity class as the Adapter Above

```
protected class AsyncTaskLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private MyListFragment f;
    AsyncTaskLoader(MyListFragment f){
        this.f=f;
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {....code...} //This takes a while..
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        f.setString("hello world"); // Will this still update the fragment created in getItem()?
    }
}
```

And the fragment class

```
    public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {
        ....code....
        public setString(String text){
            TextView str = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            str.setText(text);
        }
    }
```

Apologies if the way I explained it is hard to understand, the code should explain it better

Basically I guess the question is, even though the `ViewPager`s `getItem()` has returned the fragment, can I still change the fragments properties after in the parent Activity?

Comment: What you do should work, but it's probably more effective to put the async loading inside each fragment (started in `onCreateView`). Problem with your approach is that you can't be sure that the fragment already has it's view created and `findViewById` might still be null if you do it your way.

Comment: Good point, it shouldn't be too hard to move the AsyncTask